# R on Red Hat 7: odbcListDrivers() couldn't find drivers from /etc/odbcinst.ini

Tags: r, odbc, rhel, rodbc

I'm trying to initiate a db connection within R using odbc package.

With the function odbcListDrivers(), I should be able to see the list of available drivers.

However, even though there are valid drivers as found in /etc/odbcinst.ini, R couldn't find these drivers.

As below, I have 2 different SQL drivers.

```
cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2
UsageCount=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

But R couldn't find them

```
odbcListDrivers()
[1] name      attribute value    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

If it helps, I'm on RHEL 7.

UPDATE:
If I run R from terminal, and invoke odbcListDrivers(), the 2 drivers can be found.
However, if I run R from within RStudio Server (community version), odbcListDrivers() still fail to find these 2 drivers.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a guess: do both files exist? have you recently restarted R? (I don't know for certain that R will look again once files have been updated.) Do you the user have at least read access to those files?

Comment: Yes, both files exist. I checked the permission, everyone has read execute access to the files.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much else to suggest besides various combinations of: reinstall the rhel package equivalents of ubuntu's `libodbc1`, `unixodbc`, `unixodbc-dev`, `odbcinst`, and perhaps `mssqlodbc17`; reinstall R's `odbc` package; restart R without a local project `.Rdata` file.

Comment: I found something. If I run R from terminal, I can find the 2 drivers using odbcListDrivers(), but if I run R from RStudio, it couldn't fine the 2 drivers.

Comment: Okay, that's useful. Unfortunately, I don't get the same behavior (though since I don't use RStudio normally, just R in emacs/ess, I don't know if this is version-dependent or something else). Good luck hunting that down!